# How to run a binary file in shell that's not in current directory?

Tags: shell

I have a binary file that's not in the current directly, I want to execute this binary file from shell.

For example, the binary file is `bin.exe`, and it is located in `C:/a/b/c/bin.exe`

If I am now at C:/, how do I execute it in shell? Thanks.

EDIT: In Unix Bash Shell

Comment: You say `shell` and you also say `C:\ `... Are you in Windows or Linux? Cygwin? Should be the same in all of them I suppose: `a/b/c/bin.exe`

Comment: Specify the appropriate path (relative or absolute) *along* with the filename.

Comment: It's still not entirely clear what system you're using. The existence of `C:` (which doesn't tend to exist under Unix or Linux) and the `.exe` suffix (which Unix and Linux don't use) both suggest Windows -- but the fact that you're using `bash` suggests you're using some Unix-like subsystem, possibly Cygwin. Please be specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like you said, just type:

```
C:/a/b/c/bin.exe
```

Note that / works for some versions of Windows (like Pro versions), but don't for others (like Home versions). A safer method is to use

```
C:\a\b\c\bin.exe
```